# checking the nth field on the n'th line within a range and other awk questions

Tags: unix, if-statement, awk

I have a file that has a reapeating pattern like this for about 30000 lines total:

```
K     102940
-1.34869738    20.57483945   -50.68597047
23.77974649   -24.07345423    15.78597590
---
K     102942
-1.34869738    20.57483945   -50.68597047
23.77974649   -24.07345423    15.78597590
---
```

I need to check the third field on the second line, if it falls within the range -20 and +20, then I'd like to print only the line that follows (the third line in above example). If the value is not in the range (as above) I want to the check the 2+100th line (ignoring the bunch of lines inbetween). Heres what I have so far:

```
awk -v l=2 -v d=100 'NR==l'; 'if ($3 =={-20..20}); {getline;print;exit}; else (l+=d) next; fi' inputfile
```

but the error '-bash: if ... next: command not found

Anyone got any ideas how to improve the code?
Or perhaps a better way to process this file?

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The immediate problem is the unquoted semicolon after `'NR==1'`. If you want it to be in the Awk script, it has to be inside the quotes--trade just `;` for `';'`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried ';' and it was attempting to read ; as the input file, so i figured i would try 'NR==l ; if... fi'. Note as well I'm specifying the variable l in NR not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should provide you with a good start:

```
print_flag {                  # if the print flag is set print the line
    print $0
    exit                      # exit the script as the match was printed
}
block_flag {                  # if the block_flag is set check if the value of
    if ($3 > -20 && $3 < 20)  # $3 is in range and set the print_flag
        print_flag = 1                      
    block_flag = 0            # unset the block_flag
}
$1=="K" {                     # if the line starts with a single k
    block_flag = 1            # we are in a new block: set a flag
}
```

Save it to a file such as `script.awk` and run like:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
```

This will print the third line of any block if the third value on the second line is within range. I assumed here that every new block starts with a single `K` in the first field.

Comment: Thank you, I have no idea what print_flag does but it seems to print a useful output, i.e the line after that 3rd field. Is it possible thought to check on the 2nd then 102nd and 202nd ect. and stoping once its found? (Reason being, the first 4 lines relate to the first 4 lines after 100. I was hoping to eventually check the 5th-8th lines and 105-108th lines in seperate loops and so on.)

Comment: It doesn't do anything per se, I just use it a boolean to print the second line after each block. You could easily check the second line, then the 102,202.. but check for what? `stoping once its found` stop once what is found?

Comment: thanks, hopefully I can clarify: after finding a block where the 2nd line and field $3 is within the range and after printing the 3rd line I'd like it to stop searching. Also, I want to search the 2nd then 102, 202 etc. Edit: spelling

Comment: Stopping is easy, just call `exit` I have modified the script to do this. To check the 2,102,202 lines, I would probably use the modulus operator `%` and the awk variable `NR` which contains the current record number (i.e the line number).

Comment: Thanks, I'll work out a way for checking the different lines. You da man.